# lerna run build command fails in lint-staged

Tags: reactjs, lerna, husky, lint-staged

I am working on a React monorepo and I have the below scripts in the root `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "lerna run build",
},
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
    }
  },
```

`lint-staged.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  '**/*.*': 'yarn build',
};
```

When I commit the code, the commit fails with the below error:

```
✖ yarn build:
ERR! lerna Unknown arguments: /Users/xyz/lint-staged.config.js, /Users/xyz/package.json
error Command failed with exit code 1.
$ lerna run build /Users/xyz/lint-staged.config.js /Users/xyz/package.json
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```

In the monorepo packages folder, the `package.json` contains the scripts as below:
`package/webApp/package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "run-s clean compile",
    "clean": "rm -rf *.tsbuildinfo & rm -rf build && rm -rf tmp",
    "compile": "run-p compile:*",
}
```

**Can't we run the build command in lint-staged or is something missing in my implementation?**

Thanks

Comment: Why would you WANT to run the `build` command with `lint-staged`? It's for linting files, not building them. The most typical config for a typescript project would be `{ "*.ts": "eslint" }`, which says "for all of the `.ts` files that have been changed, run `eslint file1.ts file2.ts`.  What you have currently would match all files, not just the lintable ones, and then execute e.g. `yarn build /Users/xyz/lint-staged.config.js /Users/xyz/package.json`, which would in turn call `lerna run build /Users/xyz/lint-staged.config.js /Users/xyz/package.json`, which is what the error means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lint-staged` is passing filenames to the `build` script, whereas `lerna` thinks these are being arguments and can't resolve them. To avoid passing the filenames to the `build` script, try to change your `lint-staged` configuration to the following

```js
// lint-staged.config.js

module.exports = {
  '**/*.*': () => 'yarn build',
};
```

Here is the link to a similar example in the `lint-staged` - [Link](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#example-run-tsc-on-changes-to-typescript-files-but-do-not-pass-any-filename-arguments)